# Is there any way to rearrange the table's fields in Rails migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

After the table creation, I want to rearrange its fields in a different order, and take care about its stored data.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use after in a change column statement:

```
def up
  change_column :your_table, :some_column, :integer, after: :other_column
end
```

Comment: ThanX first, but what about the data stored in these fields?

Comment: I just tested it on Rails 4 w/postgres and changing the field from :string to text, or leaving it the same type as it already is did not delete the data in the specified field

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a separate migration to change column.

```
rails g migration change_data_type_for_fieldname

class ChangeDataTypeForFieldname < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    #change column type form int to  bigint
    change_column :my_table, :my_column, :bigint
  end
  def down
    #change column type form bigint to  int
    change_column :my_table, :my_column, :int
  end
end
```

Please refer [api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column)